# only single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to perform the following Sqlite query:

```
SELECT * FROM monsters WHERE ( uid IN added_monsters )
```

with this table:

```
create table if not exists added_monsters(STRING name, INTEGER uid)
```

but I get an error "only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression".

Comment: The query is not nested properly please give the schema as well as your query you wish to perform verbally

Comment: Its because you are returning more than one result.Try `SELECT * FROM monsters WHERE ( uid IN added_monsters ) limit 1`

Comment: I want to get a list of monsters, which unique ids are also stored in another table.
@Gandalf I used your command but still get the same problem

Comment: can you post the value of added_monsters and uid?

Comment: added_monsters is a table that I create using
"create table if not exists added_monsters(STRING name, INTEGER uid)"

Comment: You need something like `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE ( SELECT group_concat( concat( id) SEPARATOR ',')
 FROM bar)`

Comment: Maybe this will help  `SELECT * FROM monsters WHERE ( SELECT group_concat( concat( id) SEPARATOR ',')
 FROM added_monsters)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had to perform an INNER JOIN to get the information I needed:
"SELECT * FROM monsters INNER JOIN added_monsters ON monsters.uid = added_monsters.uid;"

Answer (score 13):

`added_monsters` has two columns, so the database does not know which one to check with the IN.

You have to extract a single column:

```
SELECT * FROM monsters WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid FROM added_monsters)
```